# DateTime function unix timestamp converting wrong

Tags: php

I am using DateTime function of php. I get a date from a calendar in format d-m-Y and pass it via ajax to my function. I am getting the date right till this step.
When I try to store the date in unix format using:

```
$ai_ff_date=DateTime::CreateFromFormat('d-m-Y', $data['date']); 

$final_date=$ai_ff_date->format('U');
```

The date stored is wrong. Suppose the date I passed via ajax is 26-12-2016 then in database 27-12-2016 is stored. Why its counting one more day then the input.

Comment: Because its add hours and min to extra day .... just use validation to set your desire time

Comment: how to stop that ?

Comment: The Unix Timestamp is UTC, but the date inputted isnt. Same date will result in different Unix Timestamp depending on the time zone configured in PHP config file, because they are not supposed to be the same date around the world. Notice `DateTime::createFromFormat` also accepts a third optional parameter to specify a custom time zone where you can specify the correct zone of the date you are inserting.

Comment: i have update the code .. try that

Comment: @param, have you tried my code?

Comment: yups its not working same error

Comment: can you please , provide me a value of $data['date'] ?

Comment: @SoniVimal Ihave provided the value already in question

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 day', $stop_date));
$ai_ff_date=DateTime::CreateFromFormat('d-m-Y',$date); 
$final_date=$ai_ff_date->format('U');
```

and please check the variable (code not tested)

Comment: Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: can i know the format of date in $data['date'] ?? 12-16-2013 or 12/16/2013

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130463/discussion-between-kashif-and-param-veer).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to convert the Date-Format to `"Y-m-d"` First and then call-in the `DateTime()` Constructor. However, since what you are trying to do is just get the TimeStamp you might also do that directly without using DateTime. The Snippet below shows what is meant here:

```
<?php

    $data   =  ['date'=>"13-12-2016"];    //<== JUST AN EXAMPLE FOR TESTING!!! 
    // SIMPLY CONVERT THE DATE TO Y-m-d FIRST.
    $dateYMD    = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data['date']));

    // THEN USE DateTime CONSTRUCTOR TO CREATE A NEW DateTime INSTANCE
    // AND THEN RUN THE FORMAT YOU WISH::
    $final_date = (new DateTime($dateYMD))->format('U');


    var_dump($final_date);                   //<== YIELDS: string '1481583600' (length=10) 
    var_dump(date("Y-m-d", $final_date));    //<== YIELDS: string '2016-12-13' (length=10)
```